# Paypal button in Angular 10 - force "Pay by debit or credit card" to open a new window

Tags: angular, paypal

I have a working Paypal button in Angular 10 app. The issue is that "Paypal" button opens a new window but "Pay by debit or credit card" button opens an inline form. Exactly like here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/

Is there a trick to open Paypal form in a new window in both options and to avoid inline form?

Answer (score 1):

The black Debit or Credit Card button always renders inline (exception: a few countries it isn't enabled for). Most people want this, and consider it nice.

There's no way to make the black button open a window. You can disable it, leaving only the normal PayPal button, which has the other behavior.

---

late edit: if you add an `onShippingChange` callback which returns true, this feature doesn't work with the inline form and so will force the popup experience