# any idea how to pass down style props in to @paypal/paypal-js PayPalButtons component?

Tags: reactjs, paypal

I am using  @paypal/paypal-js from npm in react app to integrate payment, any idea how to pass down style props in the button component that this library offers ?

```js
// Style logic form paypal devoloper
paypal.Buttons({
  style: {
    layout:  'vertical',
    color:   'blue',
    shape:   'rect',
    label:   'paypal'
  }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');

// module
import React from 'react';
import {  PayPalButtons } from '@paypal/react-paypal-js';

interface Props {}

export const PaypalCheckoutButtons: React.FC<Props> = ({}) => {
  return <PayPalButtons />;
};
```

Comment: It looks like it already accepts a style config? I've never used this library, but if you checked the documentation and their component doesn't allow more granular customization you would have to try overriding their CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some examples in [the documentation](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--donate). For your case:

```
    <PayPalButtons
        style={{
            layout:  'vertical',
            color:   'blue',
            shape:   'rect',
            label:   'paypal'
        }}
    />
```

Comment: any idea how to make the creditcard option open in a paypal box rather than the new way of opening ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63735414/paypal-button-in-angular-10-force-pay-by-debit-or-credit-card-to-open-a-new

Comment: I have to disagree with your answer there check this payment on this web site the cerditcard opens new PayPal window exactly as op in angular question is asking for https://www.resumemaker.online/ there must be a way to do it, but when it comes to inline model it look nice for sure.